# Index Matrix Rows and Columns on MATLAB, is this code ok?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, matrix

I have some code on MATLAB, which I have to translate it to Python to work with it. Going through the code I found this line:

```
filtered_proj (new_len, :, 1) = 0;
```

So after reading here [MATLAB Documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html), I understood and tried to apply on my Python code. I created a matrix in Python using NumPy to test:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

but when I try to access like it is written on MATLAB, with the following python code

```
a[1,:,1]
```

I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

If I access like `a[1: ,1]` I get this:

```
array([4, 6])
```

And like `a[1,: 1]` I get this:

```
array([3])
```

So, is this MATLAB code really correct? If it is, how should I do that?

Comment: Can you please add your MATLAB code? We may be able to solve your problem if so.

Comment: what is the variable ``new_len`` ?

Comment: what is your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MATLAB index suggests that you have a 3D array. Your numpy array is a 2D matrix of 3 rows, 2 columns. You need to create a 3D array for your test to work. Also, keep in mind that numpy indices start at zero while MATLAB indices start at 1.

The index `a[1:, 1]` gets the second element of every column, on all rows starting with the second. So `[4, 6]` is exactly the expected result.

Similarly, `a[1, :1]` fetches second row up to (but not including) the second column. Since the row has two elements, it correctly returns `[3]`.

For a 3D index like `a[1, :, 1]` or `a[0, :, 0]` to work, initialize your test array as a 3D array:

```
a = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], [[7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]])
```

or better yet:

```
a = np.arange(1, 13).reshape(2, 3, 2)
```

Now `a[0, :, 0]` gives `[1, 3, 5]` and `a[1, :, 1]` gives `[8, 10, 12]`, as expected.

Comment: Thanks! It really helped. And checking again the whole MATLAB code (the code is scattered around 13 files, that's why I got confused) yes, the matrix is 3D. Now I understand what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Without more context on your MATLAB code I can't comment on whether the MATLAB code is correct.

But 
`myMatrix = numpy.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])`
creates a 3 x 2 matrix, where there are 3 rows of length 2. These three rows are [1,2], [3,4], [5,6], as specified in your input. The outer bracket around all of this tells numpy that you are creating a matrix.

The syntax `a[1,:,1]` fails because there are only 2 dimensions, not 3, in your array you created. These dimensions are: the row "dimension" and the column "dimension."

Answer (score 2):

First, check the dimension of the `filtered_proj` variable in your Matlab workspace (i.e. run `ndims(filtered_proj)`). If it is 3d, then the other answers apply, but if it is a 2d matrix, I have the answer for you.

---

Given a variable with dimension, *n*, Matlab is flexible about indexing with more than *n* dimensions **provided** the additional indices are 1.

For example,

```
X = 5;
display(X(1,1,1,1,1));
```

Will display 5

But

```
X = 5;
display(X(1,1,1,1,5));
```

Will throw an error "Index exceeds matrix dimensions."

In your numpy code, you declare a 2d matrix. In Matlab, you can index into a 2d matrix using `a(1,:,1)` because the final index is 1. However, Numpy is stricter and throws an error.

Therefore, when you translate the code from Matlab to numpy, you must remove the additional dimension from command, i.e. `a[1,:]`.

Comment: This may not be all of what OP needs, but it has really great info. +1